# Unresponsive GUI on New Operating System

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to triage an issue that has surfaced when some servers were upgraded from Windows Server 2008 to 2012. The application is a .NET 3.5 C# WinForms application that spins up a thread to run some potentially very long-running stored procedures.

The background thread is set up like this:

```
t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(StartProcess));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
t.Start();
```

StartProcess() fires off some status updates back to the UI thread that work fine and then eventually gets to a call like this:

```
// cmd is configured with a CommandTimeout value of 0
using( SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) )
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(ds);

    return ds;
}
```

The `Fill()` call works fine for short-running sprocs, but if a long-running one is used (execution time in hours), the GUI ends up becoming unresponsive after 15-45 minutes. The associated sproc will run to completion, but the GUI won't update again.

What additional information would be needed to diagnose the issue? Is there some inherent difference between the two OS versions to make this implementation problematic?

I should also mention that this application will work fine when run in debug mode via Visual Studio; it is only when running the deployed, release-mode version that the hangs occur. I've tried creating a simple WinForms application that calls a sproc that simply uses a `WAITFOR` to simulate a 50 minute run time, but that does not exhibit the unresponsiveness seen in the actual application.

Comment: Why are you marshalling the `da.Fill` to the UI thread? That's where the DB work is happening. Let it happen asynchronously or in a separate thread, and return just the prepared data set back to the UI thread.

Comment: `da.Fill` is not on the UI thread, it is occuring on the thread `t`.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition that somehow didn't trigger under Win 2k8 and doesn't for some reason (optimizations?) happen under Visual Studio. Can't you attach a debugger to the process when run outside Visual Studio? (in VS, Debug -> Attach to Process) once it looks unresponsive?

Comment: Are you using a new `SqlConnection` on that processing thread? MS SQL doesn't allow you to have more than one data reader on a single `SqlConnection`, so when the stored procedure finally gets to the point where it starts reading the cursor, it will cause all the commands from other threads to fail - this could produce the behaviour you're seeing if you're using the same `SqlConnection` from different threads - it's not thread-safe. Just create a new connection in that case.

Comment: @Luaan was about to add that too

Comment: Ya I think Luaan is on right track, the da.Fill causes the SQL to fire and do the work on the GUI thread.  But there is also one other thing to consider which is this.  Assume that you have all the data from another thread and you are attempting to fill up a grid for display, if you are attempting to fill in zillions of records, you are causing the rendering engine (which you have zero control) to block the GUI thread until the render is complete.  This is why you should only fill in minimal amounts and let user choose what else they want.  You can also use Reactive Extensions as well.

Comment: My psychic debugger says that you can repro this by locking the workstation, Win+L key.  Best done on the machine itself, you might repro it as well on your dev machine.

Comment: @HansPassant that is very interesting actually. Can you expand or give some links?

Comment: @JohnPeters for this particular app, the result set is not being used in the UI, could you expand on why the `da.Fill` causes the work to be done on the GUI thread? And why would this work in Server 2008 and not 2012?

Comment: @Luaan yes, a new SqlConnection is being used for this thread (all data access actually happens from this thread). A new connection is used for each stored procedure call.

Comment: "Windows server and WinForms": how is this application started ? Normally by a logged on user as a frontend GUI, or e.g. via a scheduled task in the background, or started from a Windows service without desktop ?
I know of a windows service (written by some other developer) which successfully uses WPF for rendering some diagrams in the background, but this can be tricky. Probably Hans Passant was on that trip too as he suggested trying to reproduce this with locked desktop.

Comment: @RainerSchaack started by a user: it is a WinForms application with a GUI and a long-running background thread. Windows Server is merely the OS, and the upgrade of which has revealed this issue.

Comment: Well, "unresponsive" GUI always means one thing - something is blocking the UI thread. Try attaching a debugger when the GUI hangs. Or if you can't have VS on the machine, use `procdump -ma`, make a full process dump. At the very least, this is going to show you the current location of execution on all the threads - unless this is a very obscure issue, this should point you to the problematic place. Very often, this is cause by things like unwittingly `Wait`ing on a `Task` which cannot complete without marshalling back to the UI thread, deadlocking you on a single thread :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a lot of googling and the hints provided in the comments, I do believe I've been able to identify and resolve the issue.

The biggest help was this MSDN blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx) that matched exactly my experience.

Basically, I needed to attach windbg to my process when it was hung, and through windbg I was able to identify my problem as a `OnUserPreferenceChanged` issue. I then attached windbg again to my app before it hung and executed the following windbg commands:

```
!name2ee System_Windows_Forms_ni System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor
bp [JITTED_ADDRESS_FROM !name2ee CALL]".echo MarshalingControl creation detected. Callstack follows.;!clrstack;.echo"
```

And I discovered that a form was being populated/displayed via the `t` thread. I wrapped the call that did that in an `InvokeRequired` check and my problem now appears to be gone.